# Two types of footnotes

Tags: footnotes

Sorry for asking so much questions. And I think this one is pretty easy I just don't know how.

I would like to use two types of footnotes in my document. The regular `\footnote` using the arabic counting. And lets say `\footnotea` using the alphabetic way of counting.

Of course I could use the `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` command but that way it won't count from 1,2,3 and a,b,c etc.

Comment: See [this FAQ answer](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multfoot)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two packages that deal with this sort of problem: the [`manyfoot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot) package and the [`bigfoot`](http://ctan.org/pkg) package.  The `bigfoot` package loads `manyfoot` but says:

> [The] purpose of this package is to provide a one-stop solution to almost all problems related to footnotes. You can use it as a drop-in replacement of the manyfoot package, but without many of its shortcomings, and quite a few features of its own. It uses the existing document class layouts for footnotes, so you can usually use it without having to worry about the looks.

So I would probably start with it.

Note that the documentation of `bigfoot` is very sparse. It assumes all of the functionality of the `manyfoot` package, so you should use that package's documentation as the guide to how to use the package.

Here's an example of what it can do. This document has a set of per-page footnotes plus regular numbered footnotes throughout the document. I've made the per-page footnotes appear first before any numbered footnotes, even if they appear later in the text than a numbered footnote.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\fnsymbol{footnoteA}}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B} % If we omitted this declaration (and used \footnote instead), that would place the standard footnotes _above_ the \footnoteA ones.

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter} % continuous numbering of footnotes across chapters

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
This is dummy text.\footnoteB{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 1, as it currently is.}

\chapter{Document body}
This is dummy text.\footnoteB{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 2, as it currently is.}
This is dummy text.\footnoteA{I want this footnote to be introduced by the symbol \(^{*}\) and be placed above the previous footnote, even though it comes later in the text.}

\newpage

This is dummy text.\footnoteB{This numeric footnote should be prefixed by the counter 3, as it currently is.}
This is dummy text.\footnoteA{I want this footnote to be introduced by the symbol \(^{*}\) and be placed above the previous footnote, even though it comes later in the text.}

\end{document}
```