# multiple sets of footnotes

Tags: symbols, footnotes, citing

I am using a biblatex style that puts the references as footnotes and also adds them to the bibliography at the end (taken from [here](http://www.khirevich.com/latex/footnote_citation/)). In addition I want to use footnotes to move long passages, e.g. urls from tables to the bottom of the page etc. For this I would like a different set of footnotes, identified by symbols rather than numbers, so that they are not confused with the citations. I already found the footmisc package to switch from numbers to symbols, but I haven't found a way to use both numbered footnotes for citations and symbol footnotes for everything else at the same time. Can anyone help?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10987/two-types-of-footnotes

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!